# How can i raycast a particular material on an object which has different materials?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to change the color of a precise material on an object which has more than 1 material... i have a mesh collider for the object and i attach to it a script... it seems working a bit but not perfectly. When i click on any material of the object it changes the colour of the material. I would like this to happen only when i click on the material i want to change.

```
void Update()
     {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
     { 
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) )
            {
                 foreach (Material material in materialsArray)
                 {
                       if (material.name == "Square (Instance)")
                       {
                          material.SetColor("_Color", Random.ColorHSV());
                       }
                       else if(material.name == "Circle (Instance)")
                       {
                          Debug.Log("circle clicked");
                       }
```

I would like the change color to happen on the square when i click only on the square.

Comment: You can get the index of the triangle that the ray hit, then determine the material of that triangle.  [Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-material-from-raycast.53123/) is a forum thread about it that may help. The last post seems to be successful, but unfortunately it was coded in UnityScript. If you can determine how to change it to C#, that will probably help you get there.

Comment: Thanks i will try that

Comment: Good luck! If you figure it out you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here and maybe get some upvotes for it!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found, to change the color of a submesh.

```
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
        {
            MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;
            if (meshCollider != null || meshCollider.sharedMesh != null)
            {
                mesh = meshCollider.sharedMesh;
                Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
                int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

                int[] hittedTriangle = new int[]
                {
                        mesh.triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3],
                        mesh.triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1],
                        mesh.triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2]
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < mesh.subMeshCount; i++)
                {  
                    int[] subMeshTris = mesh.GetTriangles(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < subMeshTris.Length; j += 3)
                    {

                        if (subMeshTris[j] == hittedTriangle[0] &&
                            subMeshTris[j + 1] == hittedTriangle[1] &&
                            subMeshTris[j + 2] == hittedTriangle[2])
                        {

                            GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[i].color = Color.cyan;
                        }
```